# Unable to save bios settings Sony vaio

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, uefi, sony-vaio

I try to reinstall a Sony Vaio (SVE151G13M, preinstalled with windows 8) which can't start windows at all...

The first part was to find how to enter on bios

I access it by pressing the "ASSIST" button" this gave me this screen:

[image: vaio care rescue]

Where I can find the bios. In the bios I wanted to enter the legacy boot mode and enable boot on external device to be able to boot on usb. Then F10 to save and exit.

It not boot on my usb (used on others).

When I return in bios (through the same steps) the options previsously set was reset to default.

The time set in bios is good...

Is this normal ?

Tried to select "start from media" but with secure boot enabled this not work.

I tried to unzip iso directly on the hardisk (make it active and bootsect) but not working...

I tried all my ideas but can't find any solution.

Any help ?